# How to configure Kafka binded Dead Letter Queue in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

In Spring Cloud Dataflow document, there is some mentioning of 'Dead Letter Queue' which can be used for exceptions in message processing. But I did not find further on this any where. 
I am trying to configure a Kafka binded Dead Letter Queue in my processing pipeline.

Can anyone help me or point to documentation to understand more on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumer and the supported overrides are explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_consumer_properties). You'd have to specifically turn on the `enableDlq` boolean flag.

In your stream definition, at the consumer application level, you could optionally configure DLQ's and supply necessary properties at the time of stream deployment.

> dataflow:>stream create foo --definition "http | log"
>
> dataflow:>stream deploy foo --properties "app.http.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=test,app.log.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=test,app.log.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.test.consumer.enableDlq=true"

Here we are explicitly overriding the `channelName` to be "test", so we could use it at the consumer (`log`) application and enable DLQ flag.

Comment: Thanks Shabby, It helped. Shabby, I am trying to validate one more thought with you - I am planning to configure single DLQ for 4 - 5 step data flow pipeline ie. `http|processor-one|processor-two|processor-three|log`. I am just wondering if while pushing exception message into dlq, can i put some header or other information like from which processor message is coming to message.